# Java Buffer Image form online Webcam

Tags: java, servlets, webcam, bufferedimage

I have to write servlet which capture few images from the online Webcam. Every parameter like(URL, Interval, numer, and count) are send by POST method. In my servlet file I have something like that:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String url = request. getParameter("url").toString();
    int interwal = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("interwal").toString());
    int nrSt = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("nr").toString());
    int il = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("il").toString());
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    BufferedImage img;
    URL imgURL;
    File imgFile;
    for(int i=0; i<il; i++){
        try{
            imgURL = new URL(url);
            img = ImageIO.read(imgURL);
            imgFile = new File("E:\\image" + (nrSt+i) + ".jpg");
            ImageIO.write(img, "png", imgFile);
            out.print("Saved image" + (nrSt+i) + ".jpg<br>");
        } catch(IOException e){
            out.print("Error reading Image!");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            Thread.sleep(interwal*1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

What I must change to capture image form for examle this webcam: [cam](http://www.brett-robinson.com/webcam/campob.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a webcam page can be much more difficult. The one you chose as example uses a dynamic image URL which is calculated on the page using JavaScript - but it is simple enough to easily extract what you need. The next problem is that the image URL points to a service which answers with multi-part responses which `ImageIO.read()` does not seem to understand.

The following standalone code seems to successfully acquire the webcam image:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        // get webcam page
        URL url = new URL("...your example URL.../webcam/campob.html");
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(url.openStream(), "UTF-8");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(isr);
        final Pattern nullDelimiter = Pattern.compile("<<<>>>");
        String html = scanner.useDelimiter(nullDelimiter).next();
        scanner.close();

        // extract image URL from HTML
        final Pattern extractPattern = Pattern.compile(
                "^var BaseURL = \"([^\"]+)\".*"
                + "^var ImageResolution = \"([^\"]+)\".*"
                + "^var File = \"([^\"]+)\"", 
                Pattern.MULTILINE|Pattern.DOTALL);
        Matcher m = extractPattern.matcher(html);
        if (!m.find()) throw new RuntimeException();
        URL imgURL = new URL(m.group(1) + m.group(3) + m.group(2));
        System.out.println("imgURL=" + imgURL);

        // read headers into buffer 
        InputStream is = imgURL.openStream();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[131072];
        int bytes = 0;
        Pattern headersPattern = Pattern.compile(
                "^Content-Length:\\s*(\\d+)\\s*$.*?^$\\r?\\n", 
                Pattern.MULTILINE|Pattern.DOTALL);
        while (bytes < buffer.length) {
            int count = is.read(buffer, bytes, buffer.length - bytes);
            if (count < 0) break;
            bytes += count;
            m = headersPattern.matcher(new String(buffer, "ASCII"));
            if (m.find()) break;
        }

        // read rest of image bytes into buffer
        int offset = m.end();
        int contentLength = Integer.parseInt(m.group(1));
        int limit = Math.min(buffer.length, offset + contentLength);
        while (bytes < limit) {
            int count = is.read(buffer, bytes, limit - bytes);
            if (count < 0) break;
            bytes += count;
        }
        is.close();
        System.out.println("bytes=" + bytes + " offset=" + offset);

        // read image from buffer (start after header)
        is = new ByteArrayInputStream(buffer);
        is.skip(offset);
        Image img = ImageIO.read(is);
        System.out.println(img);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace(System.err);
    }
}
```

Note that the code is lacking real error handling, the buffer has fixed size etc.